# converting a large number into hexatridecimal

Tags: string, emacs, elisp, largenumber

I want to turn a large number, actually the present time in seconds counted from the unix epoch time, into a hexatridecimal string.

I hacked some code a long time ago, which (I think) worked on an earlier version of emacs, but it does not work any more on emacs 23 that I use now (It might be possible that I messed up the code).

The difficulty at the time I wrote it was that the number was large to be handled as one argument for certain functions, so I had to divide it, do something, and put them together. For example, if you give a large number to `string-to-number`, it gives back a float even though I want an integer.

Can anyone suggest a rewrite of it?

Following is the broken code that I wrote. It does not work, but may give you an idea of what I am trying to do. First, these are all subroutines that are used below:

```
(defun seconds-since-origin ()
    (string-to-number (concat
        (number-to-string (- (string-to-number
            (substring (format-time-string "%s") 0 5)
         ) 10000))
    (substring (format-time-string "%s") 5)
)))

(defun hexatridecimal (decimal)
(concat
    (let ((quotient (/ decimal 36)))    (if (> quotient 35)
        (hexatridecimal quotient)
        (hexatridecimal-digit quotient)
    ))
    (hexatridecimal-digit (% decimal 36))
))

(defun hexatridecimal-digit (number)
    (nth number (list
"0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
    "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"))
)
```

The following will be the main function that will be called:

```
(hexatridecimal (seconds-since-origin))
```

Comment: Must the code work on a 32-bit Emacs?  Or can you use 64-bit?

Comment: I did not know about emacs with 32/64-bits difference, but I am using 32-bit ubuntu linux, so it's probably 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a 64-bit Emacs (which can handle integers like you're using), make the following changes:

```
(defun seconds-since-origin ()
  (string-to-number (format-time-string "%s")))

(defun hexatridecimal (decimal)
  (let ((quotient (/ decimal 36))
        (remainder (% decimal 36)))
    (concat 
     (if (> quotient 0)
         (hexatridecimal quotient)
       "")
     (hexatridecimal-digit remainder))))
```

Note: this does assume a 64-bit Emacs which has more bits for [large integers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Integer-Basics.html) than the 32-bit builds.

If you want to work on a 32-bit Emacs, you can use [calc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/calc.html)'s big-int capability to do the maths for you, and adjust the code appropriately.

*Edited to add:*
Here's the version using `calc`'s bignum capabilities:

```
(require 'calc)
(require 'calc-ext)
(defun seconds-since-origin ()
  (math-read-number-simple (format-time-string "%s")))
(defun hexatridecimal (decimal-bignum)
  (let* ((q-r (math-idivmod decimal-bignum 36))
     (quotient (car q-r))
     (remainder (cdr q-r)))
(concat 
 (if (math-lessp 0 quotient)
     (hexatridecimal quotient)
   "")
 (hexatridecimal-digit remainder))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Mine is probably 32-bit. I am looking into the link that you gave me.

Comment: Thank you. It is of great help. I wasn't sure which page was `calc`'s page. I tried to look http://savannah.gnu.org/search/?words=calc&type_of_search=soft&Search=Search&exact=1#options

Comment: @Trey Actually, I cannot find `cal.el` and `calc-ext.el`. It would help if you can tell me where I can get it.

Comment: `M-x find-library RET calc RET` and likewise for `calc-ext`. If you don't have them, you must have an older version of Emacs, and should look up upgrading.

Comment: I did seem to have them already on my emacs, after doing `find-library`. But, the code gives me `(wrong-type-argument integerp 4.974268308285279)` I think it's still returning float somewhere. My version is GNU Emacs 23.1.1 i686-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: 23.2 has been around since last May, and 23.3 has just been released, so your version could well be the issue.

Comment: @sawa I'm guessing your problem is that you've got the wrong version of `seconds-since-origin`, b/c that's the only place that could introduce a floating point - and does so on 32-bit Emacsen.  Try the version using 'calc` (the second chunk).

Comment: @Trey It worked now. I was trying with the whole chunk that you gave me, and had something wrong, but now it works. Thank you. @phils Thanks you for the informatin about the new version of emacs. I will consider it.

Comment: @Trey The problem turned out to be that I had a corresponding `elc` file, and forgot to byte-compile the `el` file after I upgraded it with Trey's code. The kind of mistake that I have made so many times. @phils I upgraded to 23.3.1 It is working fine.